# System tray icons disappeared

Tags: 18.04, lightdm, gdm, system-tray

I have Ubuntu 18.04 on my system and recently I started using lightdm instead of the default gdm. Every thing works well except that my tray icons are not showing now.

Rarely do they show (once in 7 boots or so) but for the most part they are not there.

Any ideas on how to get them back?

Comment: Why aren't you using gdm3? Is there a bigger problem that needs solving?

Comment: I switched over from gdm3 to lightdm because I had the "login loop" issue. But since switching to lightdm, weirdly enough, my system's temperatures have been way cooler (when idle) compared to when I was using gdm3 (I don't know why and I honestly have no clue about it). So that is the reason I want to continue with lightdm.

Comment: I'll bet that if you switched back to gdm3, the login loop doesn't exist any more. It can happen if you use `sudo` in the terminal incorrectly. For temps, do you remember how big of a difference there was? I'd use the `top` command to see if some process, like gnome-shell, was consuming a lot of CPU, raising temps. You could also install `thermald` to control temps, even with lightdm. gdm3 is the future... I'd try and make it work.